# Randomly Error of `[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)` from Shopify API call

Tags: laravel, shopify, laravel-8, shopify-app

I have created Shopify public App using **osiset/laravel-shopify** package.
https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify

This app is working fine, also app is published on the Shopify App Store.

but recently I got errors of `[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)` in each Shopify API call.

#### Using versions:

`"laravel/framework": "^8.12"`

`"osiset/laravel-shopify": "^17.0",`

This is happening for all stores which are using this app.

#### Temp Solution for me.

- whenever API failed & got this error that time we update App from the store by the given URL.

"https://shop.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://shopify-app.com/authenticate&scope=read_products,write_products,read_orders,write_orders,read_customers,write_customers,read_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders,write_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders,read_inventory&grant_options[]=per-user"

one another option

- set an empty password in the user's table in the database.

After doing this App working fine for the next 2-3 days.
after 2-3 days again get these problems & fix them by updating the app from the store.

I'm not sure why & when this happens.

#### Failure Logs

Response of Failed Shopify Rest API.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for replying

- My issue was fixed. (sorry to say this is a code mistake from my side)
- I'm passing grant_options[]=per-user while Updating App from the store.
  so it's generated Online access & this token is valid for 24 hours.
- I must be the use offline-access
  https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth/access-modes#offline-access